# Post request with node to MongoDB AND render success page?

Tags: node.js, express, post, http-post

this is my HTML Form:

```
  <form id="task-form" action="/mytask" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name of task" />
    <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

I want to store the data to a MongoDB which works nice with the following code. Unfortunately I can see the JSON after clicking on the button what I don´t want of course.

```
app.post("/mytask", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {

  const task = new Task(req.body);
  task
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.send(task);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.status(400).send(e);
    });
});
```

I also want to render a thank you page which includes information from the `request.body`. This works also fine.

```
    app.post("/mytask", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
      res.render("thankyou", {
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description
      });
    });
```

But I want to do both. Store the data and render another page, something like this.

```
app.post("/mytask", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  const task = new Task(req.body);
  task
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.send(task);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.status(400).send(e);
    });

  res.render("thankyou", {
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description
  });
});
```

This seems to be not possible. Error is the following:

> [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:
>   C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyExpressApp\views\thankyou.hbs: Cannot set
>   headers after they are sent to the client

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the front end that you are using would be more helpful. By the looks of it, you are rendering just the task object which is a JSON. Thats why you see the json after you click submit in the first code.

The error occurs in the last code because, you are sending the thank you message but after the save operation has been completed, you are attempting to send an another response with the task object. You can send only one response for a request.

Possible approach would be have a new html rendered with any rendering engine or use front end frameworks like angular, react to receive the message and display it.

For example if you use ejs,the code would be something like

```
app.post("/mytask", urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
  const task = new Task(req.body);
  task
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      res.render("index", {
        name: task.name,
        description: task.description
    });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.status(400).send(e);
    });  
});
```

The index.ejs file

```
<html>
  <head><title><%= title %></title></head>
  <body>
    <p>Thank you</p>
    <p> <%= name %> </p>
    <p> <%= description%> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```